# PHP Stripe SEPA how to make recurring payment

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments, sepa

I am integrating Stripe SEPA payment method in PHP WordPress. I cannot use plugin so that is why I have to integrate it.

I have created a product in stripe dashboard and get user IBAN to subscribe the product for recurring payment.

Here is my code:

```
 $iban = $_POST['useriban'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['useremail'];

    $paymentMethod = \Stripe\PaymentMethod::create([
    'type' => 'sepa_debit',
    'sepa_debit' => [
        'iban' => $iban, // Replace with the actual IBAN
    ],
    'billing_details' => [
            'name' => $username,
            'email' => $email,
        ],
]);
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'name' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
    'payment_method' => $paymentMethod->id,
]);

 $customer_id = $customer->id;
 $customer->invoice_settings->default_payment_method = $paymentMethod->id;
$customer->save();

$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'items' => [
        [
            'price' => 'plan_ODaZeXLlnFADJZ', // Replace with the price ID of the product
        ],
    ],
    'default_source' => $paymentMethod->id, // Replace with the actual SEPA payment method ID
    'mandate' => [
        'customer_acceptance' => [
            'type' => 'online',
            'online' => [
                'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], // Replace with the customer's IP address
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

this code gives me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error sending request to Stripe: (Status 400) (Request req_4Q3bwHjriVSt6Y) Received unknown parameter: mandate Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException: Received unknown parameter: mandate in

Kindly help me how to set recurring payment and how to set mandate with subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You likely shouldn't be creating Payment Method objects directly. Recommend starting [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/sepa-debit?platform=web) for integrating SEPA Direct Debit subscriptions (includes details on how to collect mandate acknowledgement, etc).